# Collapsing multiple rows into a single row based on a common identifier

Tags: stata

Working in Stata, suppose I have a data table like this...

| Household Identifier | Person Identifier | Var1 | Var2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | a | b |
| 1 | 1 | c | d |
| 1 | 2 | e | f |
| 2 | 1 | g | h |
| 2 | 1 | i | j |
| 2 | 1 | k | l |
| 2 | 2 | m | n |
| 2 | 2 | o | p |
| 3 | 1 | q | r |

I want to be able to combine these so there is just one observation per household, i.e. like this

| Household Identifier | Person1_Var1_1 | Person1_Var2_1 | Person1_Var1_2 | Person1_Var2_2 | Person1_Var3_1 | Person1_Var3_2 | Person2_Var1_1 | Person2_Var2_1 | Person2_Var1_2 | Person2_Var2_2 | Person2_Var3_1 | Person2_Var3_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | b | c | d | . | . | e | f | . | . | . | . |
| 2 | g | h | i | j | k | l | m | n | o | p | . | . |
| 3 | q | r | . | . | . | . | . | . | . | . | . | . |

Is there a straightforward way of doing this?

Comment: Please see the `stata` tag wiki for how to present data examples as Stata code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reshape wide` twice. Note that when I create `rowid`, I add an underscore to it; I also add underscore to the `var1` and `var2` columns. In the first `reshape` call, I use `string` to identify `rowid` as a string variable

```
bysort householdidentifier personidentifier: gen rowid = strofreal(_n) + "_"
rename var* =_
reshape wide var1 var2, i(householdidentifier personidentifier) j(rowid) string
reshape wide var*, i(householdidentifier) j(personidentifier)
```

Output:

```
       househ~r   var1_1_1   var2_1_1   var1_2_1   var2_2_1   var1_3_1   var2_3_1   var1_1_2   var2_1_2   var1_2_2   var2_2_2   var1_3_2   var2_3_2  
  1.          1          a          b          c          d                                e          f                                              
  2.          2          g          h          i          j          k          l          m          n          o          p                        
  3.          3          q          r
```